# how to read SMS from specific number and delete from inbox programmatically

Tags: android

I used this code which gets SMS messages from a specific phone number and then opens my application.

It works fine but it does not delete SMS from the inbox after getting the SMS from the specific phone number.

I'm using a simulator for testing please help tell me what is the error in the code? 
How can i delete SMS from specific number???

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String specificPhoneNumber = "15555215554";

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
            //---get the SMS message passed in---
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String str = "";  

            if (bundle != null)
            {         
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                    String phNum = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();  
                    str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
             if (specificPhoneNumber.equals(phNum))

            {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

                ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

                String where = "address="+phNum;
                Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id"}, where, null,
                                  null);

                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                    long thread_id = cursor.getLong(1);
                    where = "thread_id="+thread_id;
                    Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(thread, where, null);

                }
                        Intent l = new Intent(context,AgAppMenu.class);                  
                        l.putExtra("msg",str);                   
                        l.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(l);
                    }
                }
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: Did you find out the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't let messages from specific number to pass to the inbox. To achieve this do the following things:

1. Set a high priority for your SmsReceiver

   ```
   <receiver android:name="SmsReceiver">
       <intent-filter android:priority="999">
           <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   ```
2. Use `abortBroadcast()` to prevent specific message from passing to the inbox.

Comment: Nice but doesn't work after Android 6.0  I cannot understand why but Android won't allow it anymore

Comment: This diesn't work since android 4.4: your app must be the default sms-processing program to get such a control over messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following changes -

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
```

For querying -

```
String where = "address="+phNum;
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id"}, where, null,
                  null);
```

Thread id will be the second element -

```
long thread_id = cursor.getLong(1);
where = "thread_id="+thread_id;
Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
context.getContentResolver().delete(thread, where, null);
```

Comment: its not work  also sms show in notification bar how i remove it notification bar to display incmoning sms?

Comment: i sued this code in manifiest

  <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true"> 
       
                <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
                <action android:name=
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
           </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>

Comment: one problem at a time... what does this say?

Comment: when ever new sms is come its show on notificatiob bar ow i hide to showe on notification bar? also remove from inbox ?

Comment: You cannot remove the sms notification from your application as you do not have the notification id. for deleting the sms, look at this thread - http://goo.gl/Ei8JX

Comment: yes this works now  but just tell me im using simulator now tell me if i deoloy on real device is only delete sms from specific number which i mention in code or delete all sms from inbox???